# Can we check tab index of combobox among 4 comboboxes and want to make conditions (if else) on comboboxes

Tags: c#

I want to use the tab index to check where the tab index is on combobox ... I also want to make a condition for this

```
if(combobox1 == tabindex) // check data is already in database or not
{
   get data on dridview according to combobox1.Text
}
else if(combobox 2 == tabindex) // check data is already in database or not   
{
   get data on dridview according to combobox2.Text
}
else if(combobox 3 == tabindex) // check data is already in database or not 
{
   get data on dridview according to combobox3.Text
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: It would be simpler if you could handle the `GotFocus` event of the ComboBox instead of depending on the tabindex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a = Form1.getActiveTab();
var idx = Form1.items.indexOf(a);
```

Comment: on Which Event or on which condition you want to check your Current Tabindex

Comment: on combobox @Co. Aden